# better reload a form with more content or just load the additional content?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am working on a website, that displays tasks. If you want to add a task a new part of the side is loaded and inside this part there is a form for inserting the Task informations. with click on a button you schould be able to insert information for one more task (for example two istead of one). My question is if I schould rather reload the hole part of the side with php or add the part with javascript and check how many tasks there are, when the form is committed?
which is the better programming style?
What are the advantages/ disadvantages?

I am writing an essay about this and i have to give a reason for what I did.

Comment: always consider those with slow internet its is better to be displaying something than nothing which is what would happen (to a slow internet user) if you completely reload just add a small feature

Comment: consider using Ajax if your additional feature requires information from the data base.

Comment: thank you @BobbyAxe